# Comparing rise over time of two different events

Tags: regression, linear

I have observations from two datasets (A and B). Each one has a set of observations with time as the dependent value.

What I want to do is verify that the rate of rise (slope) of A is greater than B. My plan is to fit each using a linear regression model and compare slope parameters. Is this sufficient? Or do I need to add hypothesis testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably do a linear regression with all the data together and then perform a hypothesis test.  Here, let me demonstrate.  Here is a plot of what your data might look like

[image]

We can fit a linear regression to this data including an interaction between the independent variable and the group.  In R, it looks like

```
model = lm(y~x*g, data = d)
```

Here is the output of the summary of this model

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x * g, data = d)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4254 -0.6636  0.0489  0.6665  3.1789 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.07610    0.08002   0.951    0.342    
x            0.43520    0.07028   6.193 8.64e-10 ***
gB           0.72241    0.11366   6.356 3.15e-10 ***
x:gB         2.21510    0.09853  22.482  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.009 on 996 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7812,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7805 
F-statistic:  1185 on 3 and 996 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Group A's line is given by `(Intercept) + x` and group B's line is given by `(Intercept) + gB + x + x:gB`.  So all we really care about us if `x:gB` is greater than 0.  If it is, we can conclude that the slope for group B is larger than that of group A.

Let's take a look at the confidence intervals for each parameter:

```
> confint(model)
                  2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept) -0.08092249 0.2331219
x            0.29728910 0.5731017
gB           0.49937325 0.9454452
x:gB         2.02175208 2.4084416
```

The 95% confidence interval for `x:gB` is (2.02, 2.40).  Since the interval excludes 0, we can say pretty confidently that group B has a larger slope than group A.  How much larger?  We estimate that the difference in slopes between group B and group A is 2.21.

Here is how to recreate this example in R

```
library(tidyverse)


#Simulate data
N = 1000
x = rgamma(N,2,2)
g = sample(c('A','B'), size = N, replace = T)
y = model.matrix(~x*g) %*% c(0,0.5,1,2) + rnorm(N)

#Put in a tibble
d = tibble(x = x, y = y, g = g)


d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, color = g))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1')


model = lm(y~x*g, data = d)

summary(model)

confint(model)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. I will give this a shot.